# Se puede realizar un UPDATE en un SELECT combinado con LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE ComprasHelpDesk

SELECT C.Nombre AS 'Nombre del Cliente', ISNULL(SUM(Cmp.total),0) AS 'Total Compras'  
FROM Cliente C    
LEFT JOIN Compra Cmp ON C.ClienteID = Cmp.ClienteID    
GROUP BY C.Nombre, Cmp.total
ORDER BY 1
```

Este es mi código en SQL SERVER, estoy tratando de actualizar el nombre del cliente agregando - SIN COMPRAS a los clientes que tienen en Total Compras un "0". Y si no es posible. ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Tu idea es realmente actualizar el C.Nombre en la tabla? modificarlo? o solo agregar visualmente el - SIN COMPRAS ?

Comment: Concatenar al Nombre - SIN COMPRAS

Comment: si es solo concatenar, puedes intentar sELECT C.Nombre + (CASE WHEN SUM(Cmp.total) > 0 THEN '' ELSE ' - SIN COMPRAS - ' END )  AS 'Nombre del Cliente'

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, pero es **una idea bastante mala**.

```
Create table Cliente (Nombre varchar(100), ClienteId int)
Create table Compra (Total int, ClienteId int)
Go
Insert into Cliente (Nombre, ClienteId)
values
('juan',1),
('ana',2),
('bea',3);
Insert into Compra (Total, ClienteId)
values
(10,1),
(20,1),
(10,3),
(1,3);
Go
```

Una `Update` puede contener en si misma una `Select`. Y cuando buscas los clientes sin compras, no tienes porque agrupar sus compras, ya que se supone que sino tienen compras, no tienen lineas en la tabla.

Para esto solo tienes que utilizar [LEFT JOIN](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/09/01/left-join-entender-la-combinacion-de-izquierda-y-no-perder-registros/)

```
Select *
FROM Cliente 
    left join Compra on Cliente.ClienteId = Compra.ClienteId
Where Compra.ClienteId is null;
```

[image: resultado]

Por tanto si con la select ya tenemos los clientes que no tienen compras. La update es la misma.

```
Update Cliente
Set nombre = Concat(Nombre,' - SIN COMPRAS')
FROM Cliente 
    left join Compra on Cliente.ClienteId = Compra.ClienteId
Where Compra.ClienteId is null;
```

[image: Res 2]

Pero es una **mala idea**, porque ese cliente no se llama así.

Donde necesites recuperar los datos, utiliza la misma idea, sin cambiar los datos de la tabla cliente.

```
Select case when comp.ClienteId Is null 
        then CONCAT(Cliente.nombre,' - SIN COMPRA') 
        ELSE Cliente.Nombre End as nombre
        , Cliente.ClienteId
FROM Cliente 
    outer apply 
        (
        Select top(1) * 
        from Compra 
        Where Compra.ClienteId = Cliente.ClienteId
        ) as comp;
```

Así tienes los clientes y si están sin compra se les concatena el literal solicitado al nombre.

**Nota**: Puedes utilizar por ejemplo `Left join` en lugar del operador [Apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/) si te resulta más cómodo. Es una de las múltiples maneras de hacerlo.

[image: Resultado2]

Y si quieres hacerlo ya mucho más simple, puedes crear una vista, que te facilite el trabajo. Pero es mucho **más recomendable** que ponerle el sin compra, **utilizar un atributo** que los identifique.

```
Create view dbo.ClientesEspecial As

Select Cliente.Nombre
     , Cliente.ClienteId
     , case when comp.Total IS null 
        then 1
        else 0 end As SinCompra
FROM Cliente 
    Outer apply 
       (
        Select top(1) * 
            from Compra 
            Where Compra.ClienteId = Cliente.ClienteId
        ) as comp;
```

Ahora tan solo consumirla.

[image: Res5]

Y cuando quieras utilizarla con el nombre concatenado.

```
Select case
           when c.SinCompra = 0 
           then CONCAT(c.nombre, ' - SIN COMPRA')
       ELSE c.Nombre
       End as nombre
     , c.ClienteId
       from dbo.ClientesEspecial AS c;
```

[image: Res4]